# Dynamically Sort nodes and put delimiters where it comes using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an HTML file and i want to convert to XML document only using XSLT..

I want:

1. All the nodes to be retained.
2. And all elements are sorted.
3. And code should be in dynamically.
4. i have an comma(,)between the elements so i need to handle that as delimiter like `<dl>,</dl>` as where it comes..(not only comma some speces also want to retained)

i have an huge file so i want an simple code to process all the html nodes.here i explained my codeing with the xslt 
if u understand it plz help me..

My HTML file is..

```
<span id="2102" class="one_biblio">
<span id="2103" class="one_section-title"><b>Title</b></span>
<span id="2204" class="one_authors">
    <span id="2205" class="one_author">, <!--here the comma arraives-->

        <!-- here the id value misplaced -->
        <span id="2207" class="one_surname">Surname</span>,<!--here the comma arraives-->
        <span id="2206" class="one_given-name">GivenName</span>,<!--here the comma arraives-->
  </span>
</span>
<span id="2208" class="one_title">
    <span id="2209" class="one_maintitle">technology</span>
</span>
```

And i want the Output XML file as:
  Here the attribute class value is used as element name.
  And the elements to be sorted.
  And the comma(,) should be come within the delimiter tag.

```
  <biblio id="2102" >
    <section-title id="2103" ><b>Title</b></section-title>
                <authors id="2204" >
                        <author id="2205" >
                            <dl>,</dl>  <!--here i want like this-->
                            <!-- correrct the id -->
                            <given-name id="2206" >GivenName </given-name><dl>,</dl><!--here i want like this-->
                            <surname id="2207" >Surname</surname><dl>,</dl><!--here i want like this-->
                        </author>
                    </authors>
                    <title id="2208" >
                        <maintitle id="2209" >technology</maintitle>
                    </title>             
          </biblio>
```

The XSLT i wrote is ..

```
 <xsl:template match="*[@class]">   
    <xsl:element name="{substring-after(@class, 'mps_')}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='class')]"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(current())">
        <xsl:apply-templates>    
                            <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>   
        </xsl:apply-templates>   
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template> 

Help me.......
```

Comment: Please, edit the question and explain well what you want to be done with the commas. It is very confusing. *When exactly* should a comma be copied as-is and *when exactly* it should be wrapped in a `<dl>,</dl>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="pass2">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"
           select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*"/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*[@class]" mode="pass2">
      <xsl:element name="{substring-after(@class, 'one_')}">
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='class')]"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates>
         <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:element>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
      "text()
        [../self::span[@class]
        or
         preceding-sibling::node()[1]
                            [self::span[@class]]
         ]
           [contains(., ',')]">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ',')"/>
        <dl>,</dl>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ',')"/>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed !!!):

```
<span id="2102" class="one_biblio">
    <span id="2103" class="one_section-title">
        <b>Title</b>
    </span>
    <span id="2204" class="one_authors">
        <span id="2205" class="one_author">, 
            <span id="2207" class="one_surname">Surname</span>,
            <span id="2206" class="one_given-name">GivenName</span>,
        </span>
    </span>
    <span id="2208" class="one_title">
        <span id="2209" class="one_maintitle">technology</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<biblio id="2102">
   <span id="2103" class="one_section-title">
      <b>Title</b>
   </span>
   <span id="2204" class="one_authors">
      <span id="2205" class="one_author">
         <dl>,</dl> 

         <span id="2207" class="one_surname">Surname</span>
         <dl>,</dl>

         <span id="2206" class="one_given-name">GivenName</span>
         <dl>,</dl>

      </span>
   </span>
   <span id="2208" class="one_title">
      <span id="2209" class="one_maintitle">technology</span>
   </span>
</biblio>
```

**Explanation**: Two-pass transformation. The first pass fixes the comma, the second pass does the rest of the processing.

Comment: Sorry for the very late rply.. It works well and good but the element is not sorted by id value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather brute force approach which relies on you knowing the names of the elements that will be followed with commas.

**Version 1 - Element names are known**

```
<xsl:template match="*[@class]">    
  <!-- copy the computed element name to a variable for ease of use -->
  <xsl:variable name="elementName" select="substring-after(@class, 'one_')"/>

  <xsl:element name="{$elementName}"> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='class')]"/> 

    <!-- insert "author" comma -->
    <xsl:if test="$elementName='author'"><dl>,</dl></xsl:if>

    <!-- process contents -->
      <xsl:apply-templates>     
        <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>    
      </xsl:apply-templates>

  </xsl:element> 

  <!-- insert 'given-name' and 'surname' commas -->
  <xsl:if test="$elementName='given-name' or $elementName='surname'"><dl>,</dl></xsl:if>

</xsl:template>  

<!-- strip out the 'author' commas where they would normally end up -->
<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)=','][ancestor-or-self::*[@class='one_author']"/>
```

If you can't be certain which elements will start with or be followed by commas, then another way to do it would be to check for the presence of a comma and then output it where you want it:

**Version 1 - Element names aren't known**

```
  <xsl:element name="{$elementName}"> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='class')]"/> 

    <!-- insert comma if first text child is a comma -->
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(normalize-space(text()[1]), ',')"><dl>,</dl></xsl:if>

    <!-- process contents -->
      <xsl:apply-templates>     
        <xsl:sort select="@id" data-type="number"/>    
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:element>         

  <!-- insert comma if the element is immediately followed by a comma -->
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[1])=','"><dl>,</dl></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>  

<!-- strip out the 'author' commas where they would normally end up -->
<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)=','][ancestor-or-self::*[@class='one_author']"/>
```

Whether version 2 is more suitable will depend on whether  might contain other arbitrary elements you don't know, but also relies on there being no other elements that start with or are followed by commas which you don't want to preserve.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The examples I gave you produce the desired output when I run either of them on the input you give us in this question. Try changing the last line to `<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space(.)=',']"/>` instead.